# Mongoose: New and changing attributes in the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been working with mongoose for a while and I am currently stuck with this problem:

I have a dynamic MongoDB database on which a particular collection does not have the same attributes, except the date.

Here is the example:

```
"date":20160121,"RNB":11.575466025255562,"LPN":0.13705583756345177,"SST":0,"DN":0
```

but it can have many different attributes, there's no theoretical upper limit to as to the number of attributes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bioChemSchema= new Schema({
    date:  {type: Number}

},  {strict: false});


var bcm= mongoose.model('bcm', bioChemSchema);

module.exports = bcm;
```

How ever, the GET request to my express does not return anything.

Here's the API code:

```
var bCS= require('../models/bioChemSchema');

router.get('/bio', function(req, res, next) {
  bCS.find({}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
       res.json(data);
  });
});
```

I would be grateful for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone still has this issue, it's because mongoose appends a 's' after the name of the model to the collection. Hence, it was querying for the wrong collection all along: `bcms`. This was difficult to find out since all of my other collections ended with numbers( mongoose, for some reason, does not append s in this case. ) and worked fine.

This can be fixed by:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bioChemSchema= new Schema({
    date:  {type: Number}

}, { collection : 'bcm' }, {strict: false});


var bcm= mongoose.model('bcm', bioChemSchema);

module.exports = bcm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks fine but it looks like you might have a typo in your API code. You're requiring `bCS` and then trying to invoke `bCM.find()`, I think it should be:

```
var bCS= require('../models/bioChemSchema');

router.get('/bio', function(req, res, next) {
  bCS.find({}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
       res.json(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing that out! But it still does not return anything in the API.

Comment: @QuikProBroNa ok.... can you post the code you're using to add data to your database?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the way that you are adding data to the database might be the issue. For example, you cannot use `.set()` when `strict` is false. There are some other differences you need to be aware of when `strict` is false and they can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)